# How to process hibernate exception using Spring @ControllerAdvice and problem-spring-web

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa

Hello Stackoverflow Experts,

how can I process org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException (and all other hibernate exceptions) and RuntimeException to return the following json to the frontend ?

```
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-08-18T21:03:36.174Z",
    "code": "CODE_20500",
    "status": 500,
    "details": "An internal error occurred."
  }
```

Actually I have declared my ControllerDevice and followed the steps of the Baeldung Guide at https://www.baeldung.com/problem-spring-web :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorHandlingControllerAdvice implements ProblemHandling {
}
```

I set also theses properties in the file "application.properties"

```
  spring.resources.add-mappings=false
  spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
  servlet.http.encoding.force=true
```

However I receive the following message when a duplicated primary key is trying to be saved in the database:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-08-20T08:44:11.342+02:00",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uq_mykatalog_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

For security reasons we cannot expose the database fields to the public.

I am using these library versions:

springboot version = 2.3.3.RELEASE

implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.23.0"

Please, help !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the problem library will, by default, print out the exception message included in the exception class.

What you could do is either:

1. Wrap the calls to the database in a try/catch clause (to catch Hibernate exceptions) and rethrow a custom exception that will hide the unsecure details.
2. Implement an `ExceptionHandler` for the hibernate exceptions and also rethrow a custom ones that will hide details - see the guide here https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring solution 1

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to wrap 1000 lines of code with try/catch or rethrow anything. Any Exception must be handled centrally by the @ControllerAdvice and the library  Problem Spring Web.

Comment: I can understand that - that's why I proposed the second solution that can handle that in a central way - you could probably catch `org.hibernate.HibernateException` to handle all hibernate exceptions. In this case though, you need to rethrow a custom exception - if you do not want to do that, then we need to wait for another answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Create a class "CustomException" that extends AbstractThrowableProblem and put your custom fields there. For me was the field "code".
2. put the code below in your ControllerDevice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorHandlingControllerAdvice implements ProblemHandling {

    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody CustomException onUnexpectedRuntimeException(RuntimeException e) {
        return new CustomException("CODE_20500","An Internal error occurred.", INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

It will handle any exception that extends **RuntimeException**, including the org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException